# Running ./manage.py test with postgis gives django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "_content_rendered" specified more than once

Tags: django, postgis

I'm attempting to run ./manage.py test on a django app (version 1.7.10) which has postgis (version 2.1.7) installed on it's postgres database but it's giving me this stack trace:

`File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/schema.py", line 81, in create_model
    super(PostGISSchemaEditor, self).create_model(model)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 270, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 111, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in exit
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "_content_rendered" specified more than once`

(I limited the stack trace for readability)

I've given the test user superuser permissions so that it can create the postgis extension, but still no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
    django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "_content_rendered" specified more than once
```

It means that you have error in your sql. Is it ok? It seems that column "_content_rendered" is declared in several tables, which are in your sql